# Not able to click on hardware Menu button using appium in Java

Tags: java, android, appium

I am working on automation of mobile native app using Appium in Java language. I want to click on hardware Menu button

I am using following code

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
js.executeScript("mobile: keyevent", 82);
```

and its giving me following error message

```
An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)(..)
```

Please let me know if I am doing anything wrong in my code.

Comment: driver.execute_script("mobile: keyevent", {"keycode": 82})

Comment: if above doesn't work try this :-   HashMap swipeObject = new HashMap();
  swipeObject.put("keycode", 82);
  ((JavascriptExecutor ) driver).executeScript("mobile: keyevent", swipeObject);

Comment: OR chat here with expertise :- https://gitter.im/appium/appium

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
driver.execute_script("mobile: keyevent", {"keycode": 82})
```

OR if above doesn't work try this :-

```
  HashMap swipeObject = new HashMap(); swipeObject.put("keycode", 82);

 ((JavascriptExecutor ) driver).executeScript("mobile: keyevent", swipeObject);
```

Comment: Hi @swapnil     HashMap swipeObject = new HashMap(); 
        swipeObject.put("keycode", 82); 
        ((JavascriptExecutor ) driver).executeScript("mobile: keyevent", swipeObject); works for me . Thanks for your help

Comment: @swapnil i tried your step i can get following error please guide me.....

Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Not yet implemented. Please help us: http://appium.io/get-involved.html (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 8 milliseconds